# Avoid change for users profile fields

Tags: 7, entities, users

Now in my site every logged user are able to change his profile fields (standard fields and custom fields). I am searching a way to avoid this capability for every 'normal' users (in other word i want that only the administrator have this ability).

There is a method to do this via code or via frontend?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the [Field Permissions](https://www.drupal.org/project/field_permissions) module will do what you are wanting. It allows you to determine which roles can edit, view, and create values for any field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the project [Edit Own User Account Permission](https://www.drupal.org/project/edit_own_user_account_permission). It adds a new permission to People > Permissions called "Edit own user account". You can then allow specific roles the ability to edit their own account.

Comment: Provided that you are wanting to keep the user from editing any part of their user profile, this is definitely the better solution. However this will not work if you only want to keep them from editing a few fields.